# What is the correct name for a so-called "confidence ellipse"?

Tags: terminology, ellipse

We often see the terminology "confidence ellipse". This is not correct: in dimension 2, an ellipse is a curve, and the confidence region is the interior of this curve, not the curve. Similarly, in dimension 3, an ellipsoid is a surface, not a volume. And I don't know any name for the interior of an ellipsoid (though this is a ball for an appropriate metric).

What is the correct name, in arbitrary dimension ?

- an ellipsoidal confidence region ?
- an elliptic confidence region ?
- an elliptical confidence region ?
- another name ?

In French, my mother tongue, I would hesitate between "ellipsoïdal" and "elliptique". I don't know what is the French for "elliptical".

Comment: There are 400 thousand google hits for "area of an ellipse" which is strictly speaking a meaningless phrase if ellipse is defined as a curve (area of a curve is always zero). Personally, I am happy to tolerate this slight sloppiness.

Answer (score 2):

In common English use we regularly find people using "circle" to refer to the circular disc, not just its boundary, usually without confusion of what was intended. I agree that "ellipsoid" refers to the boundary while that is simply the bounds for the confidence region but I would have little hesitation in saying *an ellipsoidal confidence region* in spite of it being a bit of a fudging of the terminology.

If you wanted to be strict you could say something like *a confidence region consisting of the interior of an ellipsoid* but that seems slightly awkward; the less precise term would be unlikely to be misunderstood in most cases.

In some situations I might say something like "ellipsoidal ball"; while not all that common, it has sometimes been used -- see for example its use on page 652 [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11559573_80) (near the middle of the page) -- and would likely be understood.

I'm unaware of a widely accepted single-word term for the [interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Ellipsoid#Interior.3F); while one probably exists, enough people may be unfamiliar with it that it might not be the ideal choice anyway.